# How to deploy a project in GCP?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-dataflow

my project consists of ingesting and processing a file with dataflow when a file arrives in the cloud storage bucket. this works for me as I develop the pipeline.py that reads the file that reaches the bucket and stores it in a BigQUery table. I also capture the event when the file arrives with the pub / sub service, this capture is done with my listener.py file.

My question is, how do I deploy the project that is developed in python in the GCP cloud, if I need the dataflow to be activated once the file reaches the bucket? what services do you recommend? is there any guide to do this?

Comment: It would be better if you share some setup related issues after following any available tutorial online.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want  to deploy a project made in Python and run it, you need to use “App Engine”.

You can see this [tutorial](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/analytic-function-concepts#def_over_clause) about how to deploy your project in GCP.

In case you want to deploy a python code which you want to execute in your bucket that triggers something, you can see this [documentation](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/python/tools/uploadinganapp).

You can see these examples to deploy a python code that triggers in the event “google.storage.object.finalize” in your bucket.

```
gcloud functions deploy hello_gcs \
--runtime python39 \
--trigger-resource YOUR_TRIGGER_BUCKET_NAME \
--trigger-event google.storage.object.finalize
```